# "No compatible server found" error came while installing mysql in windows 7

Tags: mysql

[image]
when i click on `reconfigure` it gives following screen
[image]
I'm trying to install *mysql* in windows 7 and I have downloaded mysql installer from [https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/)

I started installing it but after some time it gives the following error:

> `no compatible server found.`

I searched a lot for this, however I'm not able to install *mysql* on my system. Please give me some suggestions.

**Is there any other software that has dependency to install mysql?**

when i click on add it gives following screen
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you installing the Mysql Server?

Comment: The installation wizard has several steps. How far do you get and what options do you pick? Or you get that warning as soon as you double-click on the icon?

Comment: please see the screens that i added now

Comment: What happens when you click "Add..."? Are you offered MySQL Server? In fact I'm not sure if you want to install MySQL Server or just connect to an existing remote server :-?

Comment: i want database on my local syatem

Comment: when i click on add it opens another screen asks to select product.

Comment: Click **Add**. That Reconfigure is clearly only for the list row it's on.

Comment: when click add it asks to select product but am not able to select anything from that wizard

Comment: My copy of MySQL Installer is completely different from yours (mine is possibly an old version) but I think that empty list is not normal. Since you don't have anything important installed so far, I suggest you remove it all and check the download site in case there's a new version with bug fixes. If nothing else works, you'll have to download the MySQL Server installer separately.

Comment: please give the link which works for me am not able to find it.

Comment: That same link you've included in the question (I assume you may not have the latest version because you installed in 27th November).

Answer (score 4):

download and install  Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable. it worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I too had the same issue. What i did was,

1- uninstall the msi community installer.

2- Install visual c++ 2019 Redistributer package (https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) ([[image: Screenshot of vstudio 2019 Re..]])

3- Now install MySql Workbench from (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)
NOTE: Download the Windows (x86, 64-bit), MSI Installer 8.0.20  35.6M
Download.

4- Now install the msi community installer that you've uninstalled in step 1
(Link:https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html) 
NOTE: Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer  8.0.20  420.6M
Download [For both 64 & 32 bit ] - (mysql-installer-community-8.0.20.0.msi)

Now the workbench will be added. Add the server from the installer and now we are good to go...

Thanks for the opportunity and knowledge

Answer (score 2):

This error may be resolved by installing appropriate visual C++ version. for 5.7 its VC++ 2013 and for 8.0 its VC++ 2015.
After VC++ install rerun the installation and reinstall just server seperate. Configure it.
Then install any other tools like client etc,
(server installs with command line (Which was enough for my needs)

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Install MySQL Server from "MySQL Installer - Community" (already installed in your system.

   - While installing you would be asked to setup a server, so, just leave everything as it is and just put up a password and click next.
2. No after installation again you will see "MySQL Installer - Community". Then click "reconfigure" right in front of (**see image in link below**).
3. Then you will see the server in options. Just click it and enter password. (NOTE: let the username be "root", don't change it).

   4. After doing all this MySQL will be installed.

**https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O3YS.png**